# Ruby - SOAP using savon v.2 , nested arguments

Tags: ruby, xml, web-services, soap, savon

I need to send a specific "xsi" type integer to the webservice, it needs to be nested under "Argumetns" then under the child "anyType" when "anytype" is the specialized xsi type.

Right now this is my code:

```
:Arguments => {"AnyType" => {:"@xsi:type" => "xsd:int"}}
```

inside the "AnyType" i want the number 30, where should I put it to achieve the following XML?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Savonrb uses [gyoku](https://github.com/savonrb/gyoku) to translate hashes to xml.

You'd want to try the following:

```
:Arguments => {
  :AnyType => 30,
  :attributes! => {
    :AnyType => {
      :"xsi:type" => "xsd:int"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you and the bounty is yours